# 3 row div or table with different style for each row ( text and image)

Tags: html, css

I have been stuck on this for about a day and can't seem to figure out the best way to handle this.

I am trying to put 3 elements inline inside of a dive on multiple rows.

a bold heading, a regular text element and a small icon, that need to have spacing between each and stacked 5 times.

[image]

Here is my code, it's scaling differently in jfiddle than on my html document. but i believe the general idea is clear. 
In my mind I want to add padding to each element but I'm not sure how to pull this off.

I have included annotations for each class in my css

```css
/* Typography */

h5 {
 font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgbold', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 40px 0 20px 40px;
}

h3 {
 font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgbold', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 40px 0 0 40px;
}
p {
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 20px;
 text-align: left;
 font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', sans-serif;
}

/* Main Wrapper For Everything*/

.weatherwrapper {
 height: 1000px;
}

/* Container Housing Both Main Weather Divs*/

.weathercontainer {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 888px;
 width: 1046px;
}

/*Left Yellow Div */

.currentweather {
 height: 444px;
 width: 621px;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(134.68deg, #FDDA14 0%, #FDC814 100%);
 box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Current Weather Details */

.currentdetails {
 width: 415px;
 height: 115px;
 align: center;
}

/* Hourly box */

.weathercontent {
 height: 142px; 
 width: 541px;
 margin-left: 40px;
 border: 1px solid #ECECEC; 
 border-radius: 10px; 
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
 

/* Right Grey Div */

.forecast {
 height: 444px;
 width: 407px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #686868;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Dividing Line Forcast Div */

.weatherdivider {
 height: 1.02px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: black;
}


/* Forcast Div For Each Row */
.forecastcontent {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 407px;
}



.jumbo-padding {
 padding: 60px 0;
}

.background-blue {
 background-color: #F0F5FB;
}
```

```html
<div class="weatherwrapper jumbo-padding background-blue">
    <div class="weathercontainer">
        <h1 align="left">Weather</h1>
        <div class="currentweather">
            <h3 align="left">Current Weather</h3>
            <div class="currentdetails"> 24 degrees address etc </div>
            <div class="weathercontent"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="forecast">
            <div class="forecastcontent">
                <h5 style="color: white;"> 5 Day Weather Forecast</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="weatherdivider"></div>
            <div class="forecastcontent">
                <h5 style="color: white;">Wednesday</h5>
                <p> 19° | 11° </p>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Czilat3.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="weatherdivider"></div>
            <div class="forecastcontent">
                <h5 style="color: white;">Thursday</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="weatherdivider"></div>
            <div class="forecastcontent">
                <h5 style="color: white;">Friday</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="weatherdivider"></div>
            <div class="forecastcontent">
                <h5 style="color: white;">Saturday</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="weatherdivider"></div>
            <div class="forecastcontent">
                <h5 style="color: white;">Sunday</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: reset p and h5 display or use flex on parent , mind your padding only where needed ... https://jsfiddle.net/ecd63ouj/1/

Comment: I'd recommend learning what floats are, clearing floats, grouping "sections" of elements, and getting bootstrap

Comment: Ended up looking up flex and got it figured out thank you for the tips fellas.